# trying to access search from browser

Tags: twitter

I am trying to search users using my oauth_token and oauth_token_secret as presented on the app page on dev.twitter.com but I am getting

"Could not authenticate you."

The url I'm hitting with correct values:

https://api.twitter.com/1/users/search.json?q=foo&oauth_token=123&oauth_token_secret=abc

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing an authenticated request and it is the wrong way to authenticate it.

To do what you want, you can do something like this (here counting how many people use your app in the search) :

```
unsigned int nbTweets = 0;

Timeline tl = twitter.search("foo");    // http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=foo

foreach (Tweet t in tl) {
    // Retrieving the application used to write the tweet in the "source" field of the tweet
    String tweetHTMLSource = t.source; // tweetHTMLSource == '<a href="clientName.callbackURL" rel="nofollow">clientName</a>'

    String clientName = tweetHTMLSource.plainText; // clientName == "clientName"

    if (clientName == "MYAPPLICATION_NAME") {
        nbTweets++;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is different, as you're using the general search not requiring auth and i was using user search which requires auth

Comment: There is not any endpoints in the Twitter API for retrieving which apps are authorized by a given user. So in your case, do the request as usual (with a classic Twitter request authentication). Once you get the users, you can search in their timelines if they use your application by analysing the source of each tweet just like in my little algorithm.